# Android intent filter not launching app from browser

Tags: android, intentfilter

This is a really strange problem... last week I was using this intent filter to launch my app from the browser if a certain URL was called. It worked fine then. Today, it won't launch my app anymore.

Here is the intent filter:

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data android:host="web1.tunnlr.com"
                    android:port="12257"
                    android:pathPattern=".*androidapp.*"
                    android:scheme="http" />

        </intent-filter>
```

I'm just using a test site here as you can see. When the redirect which loads up the page http://web1.tunnlr.com/androidapp is sent to the user's browser, before it would give a little chooser dialog where you could either open the page with your browser (because http schemes are always caught by the browser) or my app. Now, it just stays on the browser. I never did anything like "remember my selection" for the browser to handle this intent, and I've even uninstalled and fresh reinstalled the app to make sure that wasn't the case.

Can anyone see an issue with this intent filter?

Also, here is the exact url I get back from the redirect, which should trigger the intent filter.

`http://web1.tunnlr.com/androidapp`

Comment: what device were u using? was that in emulator? samsung and htc devices have some problem with choosing the activities which handle the intents which match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you haven't changed the intent filter, then I would guess you accidentally set the browser to handle this intent all the time.

You can clear this by going Settings > Apps > Browser > Clear defaults

Comment: Make sure you haven't got it set for chrome or any other browser too

Answer (score 0):

Try this?

```
            <data android:host="web1.tunnlr.com"
                android:port="12257"
                android:pathPrefix="/androidapp/"
                android:pathPattern="\\*"
                android:scheme="http" />
```