# Unable to launch app from web browser

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

I'm trying to launch my app as stated here: [Launch custom android application from android browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958701/launch-custom-android-application-from-android-browser)

I've created `intent-filter` in my manifest:

```
<activity
            android:name=".ui.BaseActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTop" 
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenSize">
            <intent-filter>
                 <data android:scheme="http" android:host="somesite.com"/>
                 <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                 <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                 <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

But when I type in stock browser "somesite.com" - it loads "somesite.com" instead of launching my app. What's wrong?

P.S: this https://stackoverflow.com/a/13019256/1548085 doesn't help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typing a link in the browser doesn't start an intent: the browser just browses to that URL. The intent mechanism is only used when you follow (i.e. click) a link in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

This example launch my activity from android browser and display first 2 GET prams form URL

```
package com.example.openapp;

import java.util.List;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TextView txt1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        TextView txt2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        try{
            Uri data = getIntent().getData();
            if(data != null){
                String scheme = data.getScheme(); 
                String host = data.getHost();
                List<String> params = data.getPathSegments();
                String first = params.get(0); 
                String second = params.get(1);
                txt1.setText(first);
                txt2.setText(second);
            }
        } catch (Exception e){
        }       
    }
}
```

You need to add this in manifest and replace android host with your host:

```
     <activity
        android:name="com.example.openapp.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <data android:scheme="http" android:host="example.com"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you just put the "somesite.com" you have to put "http://somesite.com/" I realized that problem too as well.